# Why Precious stole the file from Weiss's files?

Tags: plot-explanation, precious

In Precious (2009), Weiss goes to get a cold drink for Precious.

At that time Precious steals some file from Weiss's files & puts it in her handbang.

[image]

Why did she steal that file? What is in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's her official file at the Welfare Center.

It will contain details and recommendations by her case worker that she might otherwise not be aware of.

**She's after more information.**

In this case, Weiss had recommended her for low-paying work and Precious rebels against this idea.

She refuses to drop out of the GED school to take the job as she is determined to care for her son and finish school and get a better job that the low-paying work she might otherwise be offered.